# How to make the textbox type table in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

[image]

I need to design a table like the sudoko Table where the user has to enter the numbers.Is there any way to do it in C#?or we have to use create usercontrol?

Comment: exact duplicate of [Can we design textbox into Table using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784199/can-we-design-textbox-into-table-using-c)

Comment: Yes but nobody did replied me exactly what i want

Comment: so dont ask it again, wait till someone does or better yet change your question so it's less vague, people understand and hence will answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a UserControl. By doing that you can easilly implement error highlighting and such (you know - when the 'player' enters two 7's in the same table).

I've made a non-GUI implementation of a Sudoku solver recently and it all boiled down to the data structure representing the whole board. By making this first and having your UserControl hook-up on this you'll be able to provide a nice UI based on the actual game rules.

I'd recommend making the game logic (and therefore the UserControl(s)) very general in a way that would easilly allow you to make other types of 'Sudoku' games, like the 2x3 (3x2) board style (found on 'older' Nokia phones eg.).

Comment: Exactly what you said is perfectly great .Thank you